# BluetoothSocket warm-up-time?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I currently use the following code for my BT server:

```
BluetoothSocket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
Log.i(TAG, "slave: " + clientSocket.getRemoteDevice().getName() + " " +
    clientSocket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress() + " connected!");

try {
   Thread.sleep(300); // <—— Why??
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
bw.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
bw.flush();
bw.close();
clientSocket.close();
```

As you can see I had to put a `Thread.sleep` between `accept()` and the first write, otherwise my client won't be able to read the line, outputting the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:517)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
```

What is the reason? Is there an alternative to hardcoding a waittime?

the important part of the client code:

```
bluetoothSocket.connect(); // will block until a connection is established or failed
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        if (bluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bluetoothSocket.getInputStream()));
            String line = br.readLine();
            long remoteTime = Long.parseLong(line);
            long offset = System.currentTimeMillis() - remoteTime;
            Log.e(TAG, "Offset=" + offset);
            return offset;
        } else throw new Exception("link not created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
        if (bluetoothSocket != null)
            bluetoothSocket.close();
    }
```

Comment: I partially solved it, by sending a message from the slave first, waiting till it arrives (BufferedReader) on the master, and then sending the actual message from master to the slave. Wish there would be a better approach.